# booting linux and windows 7 from 2 separate hard drives on anb ASUS motherboard

Tags: dual-boot, microsoft

I installed Linux on my computer last week on a new hard drive (I'll call this HDD1). I also have an existing hard drive which contains Windows 7 (HDD2). I can boot the computer, which contains an ASUS 68HM motherboard with linux on HDD1. How can I set up my motherboard to boot from Windows 7 as required from HDD2? I realise I could install microsoft applications as desired, using playonlinux in conjunction with Wine and I am in the process of doing this also, I just think the option of booting from an alternative hard drive would be good.

Comment: you should be able to select which hard drive and/or which OS to boot from within your "bios"

Comment: That would be the obvious solution wouldn't it? Unfortunately, when I enter the Boot screen in my bios system, the boot priority (or boot option no. as it calls it) does not include the hard drive names that appear in the Sata configuration. The boot options are: 1) UBUNTU 2) UEFI: IP4 Realtek PCIe GBE Family controller (IPV4) 3)UEFI: IP6 Realtek PCIe GBE Family controller (IPV6) 4)UEFI OS 5) disabled. Any thoughts?

Comment: You can try them and find out =)

Comment: Did that - didn't work with any of them.

Comment: You have a UEFI machine. In what modes are both OSes installed?

Comment: I'm not sure about windows. I'm pretty sure linux is installed in UEFI mode as this went straight onto my computer  although I am not at all clear of the difference to BIOS. windows was installed via a different machine (with a gigabyte motherboard). I understand that UEFI and BIOS are 2 different things but don't really understand why.

Comment: UEFI is the new bios - https://www.howtogeek.com/56958/htg-explains-how-uefi-will-replace-the-bios/

Comment: Thank you panther, that link (and the off shoots from it) are most informative. I still have no idea why I can't boot from Windows but I've increased my knowledge. Result!